# xarray - cannot serialize coordinates

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm trying to use xarray to append and write a netCDF file. Some info on the original file is below.

```
Dimensions:    (Time: 744, south_north: 289, west_east: 339)
Coordinates:
XLAT       (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
XLONG      (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: Time, south_north, west_east
Data variables:
Times      (Time) |S19 ...
RAINNC     (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
I_RAINNC   (Time, south_north, west_east) int32 ...
SNOWNC     (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
GRAUPELNC  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
HAILNC     (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
```

Here's some information on the appended file (two variables added).

```
Dimensions:    (Time: 744, south_north: 289, west_east: 339)
Coordinates:
XLAT       (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
XLONG      (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: Time, south_north, west_east
Data variables:
Times      (Time) |S19 ...
RAINNC     (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
I_RAINNC   (Time, south_north, west_east) int32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
SNOWNC     (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
GRAUPELNC  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
HAILNC     (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 ...
PRCP       (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
CUMPRCP    (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I'm attempting to write a new file with xarray.to_netcdf(), but am receiving this error:

```
ValueError: cannot serialize coordinates because variable RAINNC 
already has an attribute 'coordinates'
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

EDIT:

Data was generated through Weather and Research Forecasting Model (WRF). Data loaded via open_dataset() with decode_cf at default. Attributes for RAINNC are the same for both files and listed below.

```
OrderedDict([('FieldType', 104),
         ('MemoryOrder', 'XY '),
         ('description', 'ACCUMULATED TOTAL GRID SCALE PRECIPITATION'),
         ('units', 'mm'),
         ('stagger', ''),
         ('coordinates', 'XLONG XLAT XTIME')])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you load the first `xarray.Dataset`? What attributes are on the `RAINNC` variable, (1) in the netCDF file, (2) in the original dataset loaded with xarray and (3) in the combined dataset?

This error message is telling you that `RAINNC` has a `'coordinates'` attribute in your combined datasets. Xarray is raising an error because it uses the `'coordinates'` attribute (according to CF conventions) to save coordinates (in your case, `XLAT` and `XLONG`) to netCDF files. However, it won't do that if there is a preexisting `'coordinates'` attribute, to avoid over-writing existing data.

Usually this doesn't come up, because preexisting `'coordinates'` attributes in netCDF files on disk are removed when variables are added to `coords` in xarray's data model. However, it could arise if you are using `xarray.open_dataset()` with `decode_cf=False`, or if used some sort of manual logic to create the Dataset.

A simple work-around around would be to remove any `'coordinates'` attributes from data variables in your combined dataset (e.g., `del ds['RAINNC'].attrs['coordinates']`), but you should definitely look at those values first to make sure you aren't removing important metadata.

Comment: Data was generated through Weather and Research Forecasting Model (WRF).  Data loaded via open_dataset() with decode_cf at default.   Attributes for RAINNC are the same for both files.  Effective workaround, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with WRF files and found an easier workaround, which is to set `decode_coords=False` when invoking `xarray.open_dataset()`, for example:

```py
xr.open_dataset('wrfout_d01_2019-04-16_15_00_00', decode_coords=False).to_netcdf('test.nc')
```

Further discussed [here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1809).